# Complex multiple if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

Let I have such a dataframe (`df`)

```
ID    x1   x2   y    
1    1    0    0.21
2    1    0    0.56
3    1    1    0.34
4    0    1    0.76
5    1    1    0.06
6    1    0    0.45
7    0    1    0.56
8    0    1    0.83
9    0    1    0.64
10   0    0    0.44
11   1    0    0.54
```

I want to create a new `colunm(z)` in `df` which obey the below conditions:

```
{if(x1=1 and x2=0 and y<0.5)

then z=x2(namely 0)}

{if(x1=0 and x2=1 and y>0.5)

then z=x2(namely 1)}

else z=x1
```

Namely `z` must be outputed like below:

```
   ID  z
    1   0
    2   1
    3   1
    4   1
    5   1
    6   0
    7   1
    8   1
    9   1
    10  0
    11  1
```

How can I do this using R? `ifelse` statement seem to me so complex with these conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested `ifelse`. Consider `df` is your dataframe, then:

```
> df$z <- with(df, ifelse(x1==1 & x2==0 & y<0.5, x2, 
                          ifelse(x1==0 & x2==1 & y>0.5, x2,x1 )))
> 
> df
   ID x1 x2    y z
1   1  1  0 0.21 0
2   2  1  0 0.56 1
3   3  1  1 0.34 1
4   4  0  1 0.76 1
5   5  1  1 0.06 1
6   6  1  0 0.45 0
7   7  0  1 0.56 1
8   8  0  1 0.83 1
9   9  0  1 0.64 1
10 10  0  0 0.44 0
11 11  1  0 0.54 1
```

Comment: Could also be `ifelse( (x1==1 & x2==0 & y<0.5) | 
                          (x1==0 & x2==1 & y>0.5), x2, x1 ))`

Answer (score 3):

I dragged your conditions to my workspace and lightly editted them to make a Boolean calculation by replacing `=` with `==`; `and` with `&`; and `otherwise` with the negation of the two conditions, . The conditionals are 0 when FALSE and 1 when TRUE so act as selectors. Could also have used nested `ifelse` functions, but I often find them messy. In this case Jilber proved me misguided (but not wrong.):

```
 dat$z <- with(dat,   (x1==1 & x2==0 & y<0.5)*x2+
                      (x1==0 & x2==1 & y>0.5)*x2+
                    (!(x1==1 & x2==0 & y<0.5) & !(x1==0 & x2==1 & y>0.5))*x1)

> dat
   ID x1 x2    y z
1   1  1  0 0.21 0
2   2  1  0 0.56 1
3   3  1  1 0.34 1
4   4  0  1 0.76 1
5   5  1  1 0.06 1
6   6  1  0 0.45 0
7   7  0  1 0.56 1
8   8  0  1 0.83 1
9   9  0  1 0.64 1
10 10  0  0 0.44 0
11 11  1  0 0.54 1
```