# Complex rules for a derived variable in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a categorical variable based on combinations of values of 4-6 other categorical variables. There is no mathematical logic underlying these combinations, it's very "I before E except after C" type stuff.

In SAS, I would do it like this (calling the original variables A-F, and the new variable newvar):

```
if A=1 and F=2 then newvar = 1;
else if A=2 and B=5 then newvar = 2;
else if B=3 and D=2 then newvar = 3;
else if A=7 and C=2 and F = 1 then newvar = 4;
(several more lines like that)
else newvar=0;
```

The important thing from the example above is the ability to cascade down the list of conditions in order until one is met, and then stop and not evaluate any further conditions. For example, "B=3 and D=2" only matters if none of the other criteria put before them is already met.

But in R, there doesn't seem to be a way to put a whole bunch of else ifs together when doing variable assignment, because it's done using the subsetting operator. So instead, I'm finding myself having to write the rules in the opposite order, so that the higher-priority rules are applied later in the order and overwrite what the preceding rules have done:

```
data$newvar <- 0
(a bunch of other lines with conditions)
data$newvar[A == 7 & C == 2 & F == 1] <- 4
data$newvar[B == 3 & D == 2] <- 3
data$newvar[A == 2 & B == 5] <- 2
data$newvar[A == 1 & F == 2] <- 1
```

That works, but it seems inefficient and messy, since unlike with the repeated use of "else if" and "else" in SAS, here every conditional is evaluated, and newvar may be overwritten several times before reaching its final value.

I'm pretty new to R, and don't fully understand the "apply" family of functions yet -- is there some way I could write a function that implements my rules, using R's if/else if/else, and then apply() it to all rows in the data frame? Or some other way to do this that's better than the example code above?

(Other things I've tried: The "ifelse" package, and the "recode" function from the "car" package. Neither of those seems to be able to handle using multiple variables and multiple conditions at once.)

Comment: But unlike SAS, R does not step through line-by-line and check each and every case against each a certain number of if-then-else criteria hierarchically and assign once per row. Rather, it will subset to a block of data that matches a single if statement, which might overlap with other if statements, assigning only "number of if statements" times. The efficiency/messiness is somewhat subjective depending on which way you look at it.

Comment: Also, `with(dat, ifelse(A==7 & C==2 & F==1, 4,
                         ifelse(B==3 & D==2, 3,
                         ifelse(A==2 & B==5, 2,
                         ifelse(A==1 & F==2, 1, 0)))))` is pretty much equivalent, as someone posted below but has deleted for some reason.

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348701/complex-multiple-if-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how you would do it in Excel with nested if statements.

```
data$newvar <- NA #i like to populate with null first so I can check logic later
data$newvar <- ifelse(data$A == 2 & data$F == 2 , 1, 
ifelse(data$A == 2 & data$B == 5, 2, 
ifelse(data$B == 3 & data$D == 2, 3, 
ifelse(data$A == 7 & data$C == 2 & data$F == 1, 4, 0))))
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks like a good and very flexible way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Boolean math:

```
data$newvar <- with(data, 
          (A == 7 & C == 2 & F == 1)* 4 +
          (B == 3 & D == 2)* 3 +
          (A == 2 & B == 5)* 2 +
          (A == 1 & F == 2)* 1
                    )
```

This doesn't provide for any other default value than 0, but since that was your chosen default value, everything is good. This variation should deliver the highest match without "adding".

```
data$newvar <- with(data, pmax( 
      (A == 7 & C == 2 & F == 1)* 4,
      (B == 3 & D == 2)* 3,
      (A == 2 & B == 5)* 2,
      (A == 1 & F == 2)* 1,
       0  )      )
```

Comment: On second thought, I don't think that works here, because you could have a scenario where multiple criteria are matched (eg. "B==3 and D==2" and also "A==1 and F==2") and instead of the rules applying hierarchically so that only one matches, you would get a sum of the coefficients of all rules that match. Still, it was a pretty neat and clever idea!

Comment: Wouldn't you _want_ to know if multiple combinations matched??? I'd also like to point out that your accepted answer does NOT deliver what you asked for, There would not be any overwriting with the nested `ifelse` strategy. The first matched combo would return its second argument. If your really do want the last matched combo to "win", I can do that with boolean algebra.